# Youtube API what information is collected by Google

Tags: youtube-api

I have a written an app that leverages the YouTube API.

As part of the privacy policy, I would like to be fully transparent as to what personal information is collected by Google (IP Address, IMEI, Cookies, etc) on a mandatory (non-opt out-able) basis.

I am **not able see this information in documentation**, any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to Youtube Data API, you can see the scope it has over your data on [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3):
[image]
You may also read [Google Privacy & Terms](https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/) to know how Google manages your data.